# VBA / Macro - Cleaning Data

Tags: vba, excel-vba, macro

Olá, Eu to aqui quebrando a cabeça em como modificar uma planilha através de um macro. Alguém pode, por favor, me ajudar?

Eu tenho uma planilha (Plan1) que têm a formatação A1:AF720. Eu preciso criar um macro para que ela seja dividida em em várias outras planilhas (não abas) com 100 linhas cada. Ou seja, preciso criar 8 planilhas novas!

Obrigada!

Comment: Bem-vindo ao SOpt. Por favor, leia o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/75104), [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas) e [Seja mais específico na pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1481/75104). O código do que foi feito até agora, para aumentar as chances da pergunta ser respondida.

Answer (score 1):

Segue o código de que precisará:

```
Sub dividir_planilha()
    Dim linha_origem As Integer, coluna_origem As Integer, plan As Integer
    Dim linha_destino As Integer, coluna_destino As Integer

    linha_origem = 1
    coluna_origem = 1
    plan = 0

    Do
        Dim excel As New excel.Application
        excel.Workbooks.Add
        excel.Visible = True
        linha_destino = 1
        Do
        coluna_destino = 1
            For coluna_origem = 1 To 32
                excel.Cells(linha_destino, coluna_destino).Value = Cells(linha_origem, coluna_origem).Value
                coluna_destino = coluna_destino + 1
            Next coluna_origem
            linha_destino = linha_destino + 1
            linha_origem = linha_origem + 1
        Loop Until linha_destino = 101
        plan = plan + 1
    Loop Until plan = 8
End Sub
```